# NSStreamDelegate not receiving NSStreamEvent.HasSpaceAvailable:

Tags: ios, swift, tcp, xmpp, nsstream

I had my code working in another project, in a class with the following signature:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, NSStreamDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate  {
```

Then I moved the connection to it's own class, so I can potentially reuse it in each connection:

```
class XMPPConnection: NSObject, NSStreamDelegate
```

When I did this, I moved all the `viewDidLoad()` code into `init()`. I also tried putting that `init` code in a separate function, and calling that function after instantiating the class. That did not change anything.

I can switch between the 2 projects, the old and new, just to make sure that it's not a server problem, and doing that confirms that it's not.

After each run of the application, the result is different. It either does not call the `HasSpaceAvailable` and just sits there, or there is a `(lldb)` error thrown on thread 1 in my class `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, FBLoginViewDelegate`. That error may be related to Facebook integration though, but with `lldb` there is not much to look at. However, with each and every run, `HasSpaceAvailable` is never called, unlike the other project.

Here's the full code of the NSStreamDelegate, so there is no confusion. This class is a meant to be a fairly standard method of connection using XMPP protocol.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation


class XMPPConnection: NSObject, NSStreamDelegate { //NSObject

    var input : NSInputStream?
    var output: NSOutputStream?

    //let XMLStream: String = "<stream:stream xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' xmlns='jabber:client' to='mydomain.com' xml:lang='en' xmlns:xml='http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace'>"
    let XMLStream: String = "<stream:stream to='mydomain.com' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0'>"
    var XMLAuth: String?
    let XMLStreamEnd: String = "</stream:stream>"
    let XMLResource: String = "<iq type='set' id='bind_1'><bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind'><resource>OneSide</resource></bind></iq>"
    let XMLSession: String = "<iq type='set' id='sess_1'><session xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session'/></iq>"
    let XMLStartTLS: String = "<starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>";
    var messagesToBeSent:[String] = []
    var lastSentMessageID = 0
    var lastReceivedMessageID = 0


    init(facebookID: String) {
        super.init()
        let username = "admin@mydomain.com" //should hash device ID
        let password = "123456" //hash it
        var UTF8AuthStr = "\0\(username)\0\(password)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let Base64Str = UTF8AuthStr!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)
        XMLAuth = "<auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='PLAIN'>\(Base64Str)</auth>"
        //println(XMLAuth)

        self.connectToSocket("mydomain.com", port: 5222)
        send(self.XMLStream)
        //send(self.XMLStartTLS)
        /*send(self.XMLAuth!)
        send(self.XMLStream)
        send(self.XMLResource)
        send(self.XMLSession)*/
        //sendMessage("hi")


    }

    func connectToSocket(host: String, port: Int) {

        NSStream.getStreamsToHostWithName(host, port: port, inputStream: &(self.input), outputStream: &(self.output))

        self.input!.delegate  = self
        self.output!.delegate = self

        self.input!.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
        self.output!.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

        self.input!.open()
        self.output!.open()

        println("Connected")


        //let bytesWritten = self.output!.write(UnsafePointer(data.bytes), maxLength: data.length)

        //println(bytesWritten)


    }

    //The delegate receives this message when a given event has occurred on a given stream.
    func stream(theStream: NSStream!, handleEvent streamEvent: NSStreamEvent) {

        println("Message received")

        switch streamEvent {
        case NSStreamEvent.None:
            println("NSStreamEvent.None")
        case NSStreamEvent.OpenCompleted:
            println("NSStreamEvent.OpenCompleted")
        case NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable:
            println("NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable")
            if let inputStream = theStream as? NSInputStream {
                //println("is NSInputStream")
                if inputStream.hasBytesAvailable {
                    //println("hasBytesAvailable")
                    let bufferSize = 1024
                    var buffer = Array<UInt8>(count: bufferSize, repeatedValue: 0)

                    var bytesRead: Int = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
                    //println(bytesRead)
                    if bytesRead >= 0 {
                        lastReceivedMessageID++
                        var output: String = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: bytesRead, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                        //println("output is")
                        println(output)
                    } else {
                        println("error")
                        // Handle error
                    }
                }
            }
        case NSStreamEvent.HasSpaceAvailable:
            println("NSStreamEvent.HasSpaceAvailable")
            send(nil) //send next item
            //send next message or
            //what if there is no next message to send, and instead waiting user input?
        case NSStreamEvent.ErrorOccurred:
            println("NSStreamEvent.ErrorOccurred")
        case NSStreamEvent.EndEncountered:
            println("NSStreamEvent.EndEncountered")
        default:
            println("default")
        }
    }

    func send(message:String?){
        if (self.output!.hasSpaceAvailable){ //stream ready for input
            //println("true hasSpaceAvailable")
            var data:NSData
            var thisMessage:String
            if message == nil{ // no message specified
                if messagesToBeSent.count != 0{ //messages waiting to be sent
                    thisMessage = messagesToBeSent[0]
                    data = messagesToBeSent[0].dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!
                    messagesToBeSent.removeAtIndex(0)
                }
                else{ //no data to be sent
                    //no message specified and nothing to be sent
                    return
                }
            }
            else{
                thisMessage = message!
                data = message!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!
            }

            //println("Sent the following")
            wait()
            let bytesWritten = self.output!.write(UnsafePointer(data.bytes), maxLength: data.length)
            lastSentMessageID++
            //println(thisMessage)
            //println("Message sent to server and response is")
            //println(bytesWritten) //int count
        }
        else{ //steam busy
            println("no space available in stream")
            if message != nil{
                messagesToBeSent.append(message!)
            }
        }
    }

    func sendMessage(message:String, from:String, to:String){
        let xmlMessage = "<message to='\(to)@mydomain.com' from='\(from)@mydomain.com' type='chat' xml:lang='en'> <body>\(message)</body></message>"
        send(xmlMessage)
    }


    func wait() {
        while true {
            //println("waiting")
            if lastSentMessageID == lastReceivedMessageID {
                break
            }

            NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().runUntilDate(NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.1));
            NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.1)
        }
    }

}
```

So I can see 2 things that may have caused this. Either moving it into it's own class, and making an instance of it, or the change of inheritance. Thinking about the first possiblity, I am looking into the threading lines of code: `self.input!.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)`

After checking the `streamStatus.toRaw()`, it says `1` which is `NSStreamStatusOpening`. I'm not sure if this ever changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could reproduce the problem if the `XMPPConnection` is stored in a *local variable*,
e.g.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let conn = XMPPConnection(facebookID: "...")
    return true
}
```

The instance is deallocated when this method returns. On the other hand the stream
delegates still point to the instance, this causes the crashes. The `delegate`
property of `NSStream` is declared as

```
unowned(unsafe) var delegate: NSStreamDelegate?
```

which is the Swift equivalent of "assign" aka "unsafe_unretained". Therefore 
setting the delegate does not retain the object, and deallocating the object 
does not set the property to `nil` (as for weak references).

If the instance is stored in a *property*, e.g.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var conn : XMPPConnection!

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        conn = XMPPConnection(facebookID: "...")
        return true
    }

    // ...
}
```

then your code worked correctly in my test.

Answer (score -1):

```
           CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil, serverAddress, Server, &readStream, &writeStream)

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil, website!.host, Server, &readStream, &writeStream)

    CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream!.takeUnretainedValue(), kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue)
    CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream!.takeUnretainedValue(), kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue)
            inputStream = readStream!.takeUnretainedValue();
            outputStream = writeStream!.takeUnretainedValue();
```